# Aligning column names and values in SQL insert statements

Tags: python, sql, regex, bash

I have insert statements like below

```
INSERT INTO KeyValue (id, key, value) VALUES (101, 'color', 'green');
INSERT INTO KeyValue (id, key, value) VALUES (102, 'color', 'green');
INSERT INTO KeyValue (id, key, value) VALUES (103, 'color', 'green');
```

Is there a way to align the column names and values so that it is easy to read the values (value is beneath the column name)?

Like

```
INSERT INTO KeyValue (id,   key,     value) 
            VALUES   (101, 'color', 'green');
INSERT INTO KeyValue (id,   key,     value) 
            VALUES   (102, 'color', 'green');
INSERT INTO KeyValue (id,   key,     value) 
            VALUES   (103, 'color', 'green');
```

Is there a tool for this? Ok with any SQL, shell, python, regex trick.

Comment: Any good text editor (I use Sublime Text) can do this for you. see... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22099813/sublime-text-2-multiple-line-edit

Comment: Here you go! Copy the logic into your language. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74573661/how-where-to-format-insert-statement-by-aligning-columns-with-values/74609752#74609752

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use `INSERT INTO SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO KeyValue (id, key, value)
SELECT 101 AS id, 'color' AS key, 'green' AS value;
-- FROM dual -- if Oracle
```

Or multiline:

```
INSERT INTO KeyValue(
    id
   ,key
   ,value
)
SELECT 
    101     AS id
   ,'color' AS key
   ,'green' AS value;
```

Remarks:

- EAV design is common anti-pattern(it simply doesn't scale)
- key/value could be reserved words, you should avoid such identifiers
- value column has to be widetype (probably NVARCHAR), then you loose data type information for example DATE/TIMESTAMP/FLOAT/DECIMAL needs conversion

Comment: The thing is I have tables with more than 80 column and doing it by hand is tedious

Comment: @polapts https://docs.oracle.com/database/sql-developer-17.3/SQCQR/toc.htm *SQL Developer Command-Line SQLcl* + FORMAT FILE <input_file> <output_file>